# Automatic weight paint failure on only one side of rig

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

**Automatic weight paint failure on only one side of rig.**

Video: https://app.box.com/s/q7r3yryvmtecm9ljo38f8xst3rjpwk4g

Blend file: https://app.box.com/s/rb1wdvzrdh8qkfu7b2ggv7sjm7xfqc6w

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the normals were flipped on the left arm. I flipped the normals back, re-attached the mesh to the rig with automatic weights, and it worked perfectly.

I'm still getting used to Blender 2.8. Had no idea the normals were flipped.

Comment: yes the previous versions made the flipped normals more visible, I don't know why they gave it up